# Can the goalkeeper grab the ball while his teammate is trying to kick the ball out?

Tags: football, goalkeeper

Can a goalkeeper grab the ball by his hands while the ball is in play inside his penalty area and it's under control of his teammate and his teammate is trying to kick the ball out?

Comment: On the one hand, why wouldn't he be able to do that? On the other hand, why would he *want* to do that? If his teammate has it under control, then he's risking injury or a defensive mistake for absolutely no gain.

Comment: @F1Krazy The only reason I can see that this wouldn't be allowed is that it could potentially be considered a backpass.